# Typescript method overload isn't working in inherited class

Tags: typescript, methods, overloading

I hive 2 classes:

```
export interface Vec2I {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

export class Vec2 implements Vec2I {
    constructor(public x: number = 0, public y: number = 0) {}

    public set(x: Vec2I): void;
    public set(x: number, y: number): void;

    public set(x: Vec2I | number, y?: number) {
        if (typeof x === "number") {
            this.x = x;

            if (y !== undefined) {
                this.y = y;
            }
        } else {
            this.x = x.x;
            this.y = x.y;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
import { Vec2, Vec2I } from "./Vec2";

export interface Vec3I extends Vec2I {
    z: number;
}

export class Vec3 extends Vec2 implements Vec3I {
    constructor(x: number = 0, y: number = 0, public z: number = 0) {
        super(x, y);
    }

    public set(x: Vec3I): void;
    public set(x: number, y: number, z: number): void;

    public set(x: Vec3I | number, y?: number, z?: number) {
        super.set(x, y);

        if (typeof x === "number") {
            if (z !== undefined) {
                this.z = z;
            }
        } else {
            this.z = x.z;
        }
    }
}
```

and the error I see when I try to overload a method in inherited class is:

```
Property 'set' in type 'Vec3' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Vec2'.
  Type '{ (x: Vec3I): void; (x: number, y: number, z: number): void; }' is not assignable to type '{ (x: Vec2I): void; (x: number, y: number): void; }'.
    Types of parameters 'x' and 'x' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Vec3I'.
```

[image]

I don't understand the problem. Vec3I extends from Vec2I, so in should be ok to substitute in method parameters.
If I comment overloading, everything works:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct. You're trying to say that `Vec3` "is a" `Vec2` (`Vec3 extends Vec2`) but that its `set` method doesn't accept the same thing that `Vec2`'s `set` method accepts: a `Vec2I` object. You can't do that in TypeScript and most similar languages, it violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). If a `Vec3` "is a" `Vec2`, then you have to be able to use it where a `Vec2` can be used, which means you have to be able to call `set` with an argument of type `Vec2I`, you can't restrict it to only things that are also `Vec3I`s.

How you solve it depends on what you're trying to do. Looking at your classes, you could add additional overloads for the third coordinate, and handle that in the updated implementation:

```typescript
// Inherited
public set(x: Vec2I): void;
public set(x: number, y: number): void;

// Additional
public set(x: Vec3I): void;
public set(x: number, y: number, z: number): void;

// Implementation handling both
public set(x: Vec2I | Vec3I | number, y?: number, z?: number) {
    // Call the correct version of `super.set`
    if (typeof x === "object") {
        super.set(x);
    } else {
        // Here we have to assert that `y` isn't nullish, but we
        // know it isn't. I've used a type assertion function here,
        // but some would probably just use the "trust me, I know
        // it's not nullish" type assertion operator (postfix `!`).
        // I'm not a fan of avoidable type assertions, but there's
        // an argument for it here
        assertNotNullish(y);
        super.set(x, y);
    }

    if (typeof x === "number") {
        if (z !== undefined) {
            this.z = z;
        }
    } else if ("z" in x) { // *** Have to guard against `Vec2I` here
        this.z = x.z;
    }
}
```

where `assertNotNullish` is (see comments above for why I used it; you could just use the [non-nullish type assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) instead):

```typescript
function assertNotNullish<T>(value: T | null | undefined): asserts value is T {
    if (value == null) {
        throw new Error(`value expected not to be nullish`);
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABASwHYLHAZgQwGMwUA1MQgJgEkUBvAKBWZQgC4UMBXAWwCMcAbiYsAnh278hDAL4MGoSLETIUhADb4AzlrIVK6HlHVgeYLLvJVajFmpgYtCOF0IJ4ACihc+6tIVYJXgE4FABeFAAGABoUb19-FHFOYJxwqIBKejkRZni-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-GxUm5RofQGBpP1GFofxXRYui3OAANqIDhkfFAAEE6jqd91Qwe1gISQowKmChRRgwYsLGCZwM6TdDxwWIDxuQi4IfJ8jBMMwsHwBB0JQZ58EhPwMAAczrfVnmI0C2jw6xXRFWh5huFYoOo1ZKOgklEQQgBhe11GRV97Dzct+hwLQOJOFBC3PS93laQtSSjXZ9kOY5TnOK4YD4AArcs7hU7FxgvHBLLA288QJIkSEjJEEIACRwEg0xILiqhIdxNR0ANtLY0zRELdAtAwAByBAG1NWI+C4Qq4psrYEIAawwdN0EKt58oQd4UGoPLEvBIpK3wZEHJS7V2I1FUMDVDVXzgMBokqhi6zK8YYDMFA0xgI1KygVM+HwXwgTcrgnC6pKdMuZx9sKsxYloWr0xmlgEPfPLdDqwruGNRtLj6o4BoDYzLzY+A9lgJwYTOQtgWbd5buYBD2p4KtCt6ggMBQEz8EA7aTE+kh-UQdCtBK+aXhix6oZQBDuM1OA+N4ScUFwAH304mLSZxg19UNN7TQ8UQgp88z-NIm9mTse8-mjA4jhMr4wWuVcvPCxFo1lEEwU9aFYXhbyfKeV4PmViJZWFv5WUefFCWJaNLllD7MFYDYydQEAnZQSK0aS2tqfwOAer4-BMAOwtpmobKJrAUm6X1qlDcqk2UByGQgA)

The other alternative that comes to mind is to have a single generic class that accepts a type argument for the data it should be dealing with. That's often the solution you'd want to reach for, but doesn't seem appropriate in this specific case.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I don't understand why method set() with super works correctly, but overloads don't work, because method set() also have Vec2I in parent class, but even I put argument x with type Vec3I it works?
Why in this case it isn't "violates the Liskov substitution principle"? 
Vec3 have all properties needed for Vec2, so it can replace Vec2 and can't break anything.

Comment: @YuriiHorchynskyi - It works because `Vec3I` "is a" `Vec2I` (it has all the properties that `Vec2I` requires). The problem with your original code was that it relied on the opposite (`Vec2I` "is a" `Vec3I`), which isn't true, because it doesn't have the `z` property.

Comment: why it is opposite ? (Vec2I "is a" Vec3I). If I create Vec3 instance it will use set() from Vec3 firstly, then super.set() and call from Vec2. How it can be in reversed queue?

Comment: @YuriiHorchynskyi - Because of the Liskov principle mentioned above, `Vec3`'s `set` **has** to accept an object for `x` that is just a `Vec2I`, because in the general case code may be using it as though it were a `Vec2` instance, and so passing it something that's just a `Vec2I`. `Vec2I` isn't a `Vec3I`, so that doesn't work. It works the other way around (passing a `Vec3I` object into a method accepting a `Vec2I`) because `Vec3I` "is a " `Vec2I`.